# Java PhantomJSDriver disable all logs in console

Tags: java, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm developing a small console app using Selenium and I need to turn off all logs from it.

I have tried `phantomJSDriver.setLogLevel(Level.OFF);` but it does not work.
I need help.

How do I disable all logs in console application that is using Selenium and Phantomjs (GhostDriver)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()
        .usingPhantomJSExecutable(new File(VariableClass.phantomjs_file_path))
        .withLogFile(null)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 22):

This one works for me.

```
DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
String[] phantomArgs = new  String[] {
    "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"
};
dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
PhantomJSDriver phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
```

Comment: I'm using the same config file but it doesn't work, the ghost driver still print all the INFO log on the screen. This is my config lines:  phantomJSCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS, "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE");
phantomJSCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "/usr/lib/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs");

Comment: I found this in the source code:     * NOTE: This is useful only when used together with PhantomJSDriverService#PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY.
     * So it is not supposed to be used like this. But is there way to set the PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY?

Comment: Somehow it works for me without setting that property. However I see the way to set it [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/243). Maybe you can try it out.

Comment: @Hery - How do I do this in Ruby ?

Comment: This one works for me with Phantoms js 1.2 and Selenium 2.53 version.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source files of org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhanomJSDriverService while debugging, I discovered that it's actually ignoring documented log levels for ghostdriver itself.  Doing this disables the bulk of ghostdriver output:

```
Logger.getLogger(PhantomJSDriverService.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Seems that GhostDriver should be be updated to not log when

```
phantomJSCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARG‌​S, "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE");
```

is used.